# c++ SSE SIMD framework

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics

Does anyone know an open-source C++ x86 SIMD intrinsics library?

Intel supplies exactly what I need in their integrated performance primitives library, but I can't use that because of the copyrights all over the place.

**EDIT**

I already know the intrinsics provided by the compilers. What I need is a convenient interface to use them.

Comment: What functions exactly do you need?

Comment: SSE1/2 with the possibility to upgrade to SSE3/4/AVX in the future. IMO a well maintained library would have added support for all of them already

Comment: SSE2 and object-oriented ? sounds too unrelated for me.

Comment: IPP is now included with Intel's ICC compiler and there are no royalties or other licensing restrictions when you use IPP routines in your deliverables. What "copyright issues" are you experiencing, exactly ?

Comment: @Paul R.: Oh yeah. Somehow it costs 200$

Comment: @YeenFei: well, maybe I expressed myself incorrectly. I don't want to have a bunch of functions that operate one type or another, I want the functionality to be enclosed within the definition of a particular class.

Comment: @jobs34yp: ICC is **free** for non-commercial use on Linux. And if you are aiming at commercial use then the cost of the compiler is negligible compared to the benefits that you will gain on performance-critical code.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Take a look at [libsimdpp](https://github.com/p12tic/libsimdpp) header-only C++ SIMD wrapper library.

The library supports several instruction sets via single interface: SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4.1, AVX, AVX2, AVX512F, XOP, FMA3/4, NEON, NEONv2, Altivec. All of Clang, GCC, MSVC and ICC are suported.

Any differences between instruction sets are resolved by implementing the missing instructions as a combination of supported ones. As a bonus, it's possible to compile the same code for several instruction sets, link the resulting object files to a single executable and use a convenient dynamic dispatch mechanism to run the implementation most tailored to the current processor.

Comment: Is libdimdpp still supported and developed?

Comment: I don't know, but we went with version 1.0 because 2.0 was still in 'beta' and were completely disappointed. Not only that there's no documentation: There was no way of loading values into a register (the functions with names suggesting it weren't doing so) and code with float registers won't even compile. I totally advise against using it.

Comment: @Sebastian You should look into 2.0 version which is now in release-candidate stage. There should be very few bugs, if any, as all supported configurations are continuously tested. The documentation is also significantly improved. Disclaimer: I'm the author of the library.

Comment: @Sebastian: As for the issues that you have seen, have you reported them? I assume the library has been used incorrectly, as it has been used in significantly large projects without issues. Having said that, the actual 1.0 release could indeed have bugs, though mostly compiler-specific, as only limited testing have been done across all permutations of configurations that are supported and the development quickly moved on.

Comment: Well, no, I didn't report them. Looking back, at the time of writing that comment I must have been really frustrated and what I wrote was probably not entirely fair. 
We are however done with our project (semester-long homework) and I haven't looked into libsimdpp since then.

Answer (score 12):

There are several libraries that have emerged in recent years to abstract explicit SIMD programming. The most important ones:

- [Vc](http://code.compeng.uni-frankfurt.de/projects/vc)
- boost::simd (not actually in boost - part of [NT²](https://github.com/MetaScale/nt2))
- Prof. Agner Fog's [Vectorclass library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass)

The most important thing to look for is to have a usable set of types that correctly abstract the best available SIMD registers and instructions for a given target. And, obviously, full portability to systems without SIMD support.

Comment: The Vectorclass library is not under permissive license -- only GPL or commercial.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a [GLSL-style library](https://github.com/LiraNuna/glsl-sse2) that will convert to near-perfect quality ASM code.

A very common operation - cross product:

```
vec4 cross(const vec4 &a, const vec4 &b)
{
    return a.yzxw * b.zxyw - a.zxyw * b.yzxw;
}
```

would be converted to this assemly code using glsl-sse2:

```
_Z5crossRK4vec4S1_:
    movaps    (%rsi), %xmm1
    movaps    (%rdx), %xmm2
    pshufd    $201, %xmm1, %xmm5
    pshufd    $210, %xmm2, %xmm0
    pshufd    $210, %xmm1, %xmm4
    pshufd    $201, %xmm2, %xmm3
    mulps     %xmm0, %xmm5
    mulps     %xmm3, %xmm4
    subps     %xmm4, %xmm5
    movaps    %xmm5, (%rdi)
    ret
```

Please note the library isn't perfect yet, and most likely have unfound bugs as it is still new.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [AMD's SSEPlus project](http://sseplus.sourceforge.net/), might be what your after

Comment: There's no mention of anything called SSEPlus there anymore.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: AMD has this annoying habbit of breaking links, updated the link to the sourceforge page

Comment: Last update was in 2009, is it stable?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: technically the last update was in 2008, as it was only ever meant to include SSE, and thus lacks newer sets like FMA, XOP and VMX. In terms of stability, its basically just a massive set of wrappers, so it should be very stable.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has just released its new ["DirectXMath" library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It includes support for SSE2 and NEON intrinsics. Documentation looks decent too.

> The DirectXMath API provides SIMD-friendly C++ types and functions for
>   common linear algebra and graphics math operations common to DirectX
>   applications. The library provides optimized versions for Windows
>   32-bit (x86), Windows 64-bit (x64), and Windows on ARM through SSE2
>   and ARM-NEON intrinsics support in the Visual Studio compiler.

Answer (score 2):

[Vc](http://code.compeng.uni-frankfurt.de/projects/vc) is another C++ library that implements vector classes and allows writing vectorized code that is independent from the actual instruction set that is used.

Comment: Vc does not support NEON on ARM, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [macstl](http://www.pixelglow.com/macstl/) - although it was originally developed for the Mac (and PowerPC) it now works on Linux and x86 too.

Also, if you're working with images then look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) - this has SSE-optimised routines for many common image processing tasks and has C and C++ APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler? [Visual Studio C++ compiler supports a set of SIMD, SIMD2 and MMX intrinsic functions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0dh78ez%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: GCC and the Intel compiler have most/all of those as well.

Comment: I think he's looking for something more than just intrinsics (some kind of higher level abstraction, I'm guessing), but it's not clear what exactly.